# How to set hourly limit for app usage

Tags: screen-time

Apple's Screen Time can be used to set a daily limit for an app, but it doesn't let me do it on an hourly basis (e.g. 5 minutes every hour, as opposed to every day).

Is there a setting or a third-party app that allows setting this kind of limit on iOS (iphone/ipad)? On Android, [Stay Focused](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjFhrTk6d3xAhWjolwKHeRvBfkQFjAAegQIBBAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fplay.google.com%2Fstore%2Fapps%2Fdetails%3Fid%3Dcom.stayfocused%26hl%3Den_GB%26gl%3DUS&usg=AOvVaw2hJqEc_rGMNEMTBgX6WlfZ) has this functionality.